# LDAP Query Filter User's with Groups Like *x*

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

I'm currently using Python and LDAP to query Active Directory for users.

I have a list of names that are First Last. Not specific enough to find the exact user.

I would like a filter that would find all users matching 'Last, First*'
and belonging to any group with a keyword in it.

> ```
>     _filter = '''(& (objectclass=user)
>                     (objectcategory=person)
>                     (name={}*) )'''.format(search_string)
> ```

and I've tried adding...

> ```
>                     (memberOf=CN=*Keyword*,OU=Delegated,OU=Groups,DC=amr,DC=corp,DC=xxxxxx,DC=com)
> ```

To my filter, but with no success.

If this was SQL, I would write something like:

```
 Select *  
 From    
    Users 
 Where
    Users.name like 'First, Last%'    
 and Users.memberOf like 'Keyword%'
```

**Update:**

After reviewing Gabriel's answer I'm running this.

> ```
> def get_idsids(self, search_string):
>    _filter = '''(& (objectclass=user)
>                    (objectcategory=person)
>                    (anr={}) )'''.format(search_string)
>
>     # Search for user. 
>     # Will return list of users matching criteria.
>     # The results are wrapped up as a list(tuple(dict))) where the dict vals are binary strings or lists of binary strings.
>     users = self.con.search_s(ActiveDirUser.BASEDN, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, _filter, ['displayName', 'sAMAccountName', 'memberOf'])
>
>     # This line is ugly... It just converts the results to a list of ids
>     # So long as the user has at least one group with 'Keyword' in the name.
>     # upper() is used to make the Keyword requriement case insensitive.
>     return [user[1]['sAMAccountName'][0].decode() for user in users if 'KEYWORD' in ''.join(map(str, user[1]['memberOf'])).upper()]
> ```

I do wonder though, could I search for groups with 'Keyword' in the name and build filters from that? Further, would that be faster? I assume it would as AD probably hashes group membership.

I will go do some reading, but I assume group names are wildcard searchable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [Ambiguous Name Resolution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx):

```
_filter = '''(& (objectclass=user)
                (objectcategory=person)
                (anr={}) )'''.format(search_string)
```

Read that documentation to understand how it works, but it can find users if you give it a string of "first last". This is what the search box in AD Users and Computers uses.

Just be aware that you can get doubles if people have similar names. If you take my name for example: if you would search for "Gabriel Luci", and there was someone else with the name "Gabriel Luciano", you would find both of us.

This:

```
(memberOf=CN=*Keyword*,OU=Delegated,OU=Groups,DC=amr,DC=corp,DC=xxxxxx,DC=com)
```

doesn't work because you can't use wildcards on any attribute that is a `distinguishedName`, like `memberOf`.

That's for Active Directory anyway. Other LDAP directories might allow it.

If you need to check if the users are members of groups, then you can tell your search to return the `memberOf` attribute in the search (I don't know phython, but you should have a way of telling it which attributes you want returned). Then you can loop through the groups in the `memberOf` attribute and look for that keyword.

Comment: Gabriel, thank you for the suggestion (anr), I will use that. Do you have any suggestions for finding if a user is a member of a group with 'Keyword' in the name? I have just setup to have Python check for 'Keyword' in memberOf results, but it's kinda slow.

Comment: There is no way to do it all as part of one search. It shouldn't be any slower to look through the `memberOf`, as long as you got `memberOf` as part of the results from your search and not making another search to get the `memberOf` details. If you want, you can update your question with your new code for that and I can take a look.

Comment: When you say 'There is no way to do it all as part of one search.' Do you mean I should search for groups, then build filters from that?

Comment: You don't need to do a second search, no. I just mean that you can't search for "users with this name who are in groups with this word in their name". But you can search for "users with this name" and tell the search to return the `memberOf` attribute. Then use those search results to look in the `memberOf` and find groups with the names you want.

Comment: I just looked at your updated code. It looks like you are already doing that :)

Comment: No. There's two ways to do this. 1). is to review the returned memberOf for groups with 'Keyword.' 2). (If possible) is to find all groups with 'Keyword,' and then to add (| (memberOf=Group1) (memberOf=Group2) )... essentially pre-finding the groups that have 'Keyword' and filtering users based on those groups.

Comment: @jayreed Trust, although the second option will make two searches instead of one. So it depends on how much performance is an issue here (if this is going to be run multiple times, etc.)